# How to assign the increasing keys to the nodes of a complete binary tree on n nodes in inorder?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, binary-search

I'm looking at the Multiplicative Binary Search and come across this. 
It's the preparation you need to do for you to use the Multiplicative binary search procedure.

I somehow do not know how to do number 1. Can you explain how?

[image]

I thought it was getting like the formula for the binary search wherein
the index = floor of((lower+upper)/2) such that instead of using floor you'll do ceiling instead.

However I came across this example,
[image]
[image]

[image]

and see that that method only worked for full binary tree but not for those who are not full but complete binary tree.
Can you explain how the complete binary tree was deduced from the original table?